# How to add space above a form? Padding isn't working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am a bit new to `angular` and `bootstrap` so bear with me. I think form is only a part of bootstrap to make it easier.

I can't seem to `align` it well with the rest of my html. The form is at the bottom and the top of the form where it says Job Name is against the edge of the panel right above it. I want to space it more to look better. But padding/margin/css isn't working so IDK how to do it. Thanks!

```
<form name="jobForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="jobName">Job Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>By:</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required />
        <!-- $ referencing property on the form, valid comes with angular-->
        <div> reviewForm is {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try wrapping form tag with <div class="row">

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Adding a `margin-top` or `padding-top` both work on the `form` element. It must be something else in your code that is causing this problem. Is the element above the form using the `float` property?

```css
form {
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  // Both margin-top and padding-top work.
}
```

```html
<form name="jobForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="jobName">Job Name</label>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>By:</label>
    <input type="email" required/>
    <div>Text</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope. Above it are panels wrapped in a <li class="list-group-item> and thats wrapped in a <ul class = "list-group"> item.
Second Question: 
So my controller holds an array of jobs with each job having attributes like name company etc. How do I create a single object of a job in this form/html and pass it through back to controller with a ng-submit="list.addJob(job)" kind of thing? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap panel element and don't forget to add container.You maybe forgot to add css class properly, unless it works fine with bootatraps current margins and paddings.

```css
.form{
  margin:10px;
  
}
```

```html
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  
  
   <div class="panel panel-default">
  <form class="form-horizontal form" name="jobForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="jobName">Job Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >By:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
       <div> reviewForm is {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form` class on form tag & add following CSS

```
form {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is the simplest solution, You have to put simple div element above the form with some height, now their is an empty div of height 50px above the form

```html
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
    <form name="jobForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="jobName">Job Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>By:</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required />
        <!-- $ referencing property on the form, valid comes with angular-->
        <div> reviewForm is {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```